# Bootstrap4 - Menu Dropdown not appearing when using Clip Path property

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm using Clip Path property for bootstrap4 navbar. When i use this, the dropdown which is on the navbar not working. **Note:** Please see the fiddle in desktop view.

I tried using z-index property also. But the dropdown still appearing below the elements.

Actually the dropdown should be visible over the elements when click on it. Now it appears below the elements.

```css
.navbar {
  background: #ffcc29;
  padding-bottom: 50px !important;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 70%, 0% 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 70%, 0% 100%);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a> <button aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation" class="navbar-toggler" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" data-toggle="collapse" type="button"><span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span></button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <input aria-label="Search" class="form-control mr-sm-2" placeholder="Search" type="search"> <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button">Dropdown</a>
        <div aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown" class="dropdown-menu">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a> <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a> <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a> <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a> <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a><a class="dropdown-item"
            href="#">Something else here</a><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
          <a
            class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well that's how clip path works.

> The `clip-path` property in CSS allows you to specify a specific region of an element to display, rather than showing the complete area.

So, it hides the rest of the element.

You can achieve what you want in other ways, for example using a pseudo element, shaped like a triangle, like in the below example. Or [jsFIddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3shbf146/)

```css
.navbar {
  background: #ffcc29;
  padding-bottom: 50px !important;
}

.navbar:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-width: 30px 100vw 0px 0;
  border-color: transparent white transparent transparent;
  border-style: solid;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a> <button aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation" class="navbar-toggler" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" data-toggle="collapse" type="button"><span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span></button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <input aria-label="Search" class="form-control mr-sm-2" placeholder="Search" type="search"> <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button">Dropdown</a>
        <div aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown" class="dropdown-menu">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a> <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a> <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a> <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a> <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a><a class="dropdown-item"
            href="#">Something else here</a><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```